# Using Images as Plane with sound

Tags: 3d-view, image, audio

I add a few people, who were recorded behind a green screen and released using Images as Planes, in my video. But when I play it in the viewport, the sound of the video is not played. Can I somehow adjust it so that the video then also runs with sound?
Thanks!

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: As far as i know, you can not add images as plane with sound, you could add the sound to the Video sequencer or use a Spaker object (Shift + A >Speaker.

Comment: Oh man too bad :( With a speaker object I would have to adjust the sound whenever I adjust the offset etc. of the video. Hmm..

Comment: Most of the time, background replacement is made in a compositing tool like After effect, nuke, davinci Fusion, blender video sequencer and so, so you don't have to complicate much about the sounds like dialogues

Comment: Yeah but the cool thing with images as planes is that I can actually place such a person in the world and that he can, for example, partly stand behind an object, etc.